# The onBind method: how to make it selective?

Tags: android, android-service, android-2.3-gingerbread

I would like that only certain applications can perform bind to a service. Can I prevent some applications to bind to a service via suitable code in the service? For example, if the service has a list of allowed applications (ie, a simple string array with their package names), could allow binding only to applications that are listed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a permission in the androidmanifest.xml under the element `<service>` using `android:permission`.  Have a look at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html.

Comment: I need to handle it programmatically, because the service should launch an application using its package name and then it should allow the binding to only this application.

Comment: Do you mean that you only want one of your applications to bind to the service at any one time?  If so can't you just do a check on a member variable in the `Service` and if it is already bound, refuse to bind again.  Also why don't you use an `intent-filter` in the manifest to start the application from the `Service`

Comment: It could be a solution (to check if the service is already bound and refuse to bind again): should I make so the `onBind` method returns `null` if the service is already bound? For the manifest, I didn't use it because I want the user to establish which applications can connect to the service and I don't know if you can do with the manifest: could I set the permissions programmatically?

Comment: As far as I am aware you can access permissions through classes such as `ActivityInfo` and `ApplicationInfo` and `PackageInfo` but they only appear to be read only.  Each application can have its own launch `Intent` action and the `Service` could always query `SharedPreferences` as to which applications can connect, setting that, presumably, via a `Service` config application (i.e. the application that contains the `Service`.

Comment: `Should I make the onBind method return null`.  Yes I think that is your only solution.

Comment: Even if the `onBind` method returns `null`, the service is bound. How is it possible?

Comment: How about checking the `Intent` that tries to start the `Service` for an allowed list of `Activity.class`.  An `IntentService` may work better for that.  These ways you would not bind to the `Service`, just use `startService`

Comment: I correct myself: if the `onBind` method returns `null`, the service is not bound, but the `bindService` method returns `true`. Why does it return `true` and not `false`?

Comment: have a look in the android source code.  my guess is that it returns true because it completed successfully not that it bound.

Comment: I just read [this source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.3_r1/android/app/ContextImpl.java#863) and it seems that it will return false if the connection is not established.

Comment: looks like you need to make res < 0 if thats possible.

Comment: Otherwise I could use a timer: if the `onServiceConnected` method is not invoked within a certain time interval (for example, 10 seconds), then the application assumes that the connection request was rejected.

Comment: However I should try if the problem persists even in Android 4.0.3.